# Creating a Spring MVC project in Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven

HIi,
I try to figure out the best way to set up a fully functionally Spring MVC project for use in Eclipse.

What I did so far:

1. Create new project with "New Project > Spring > Spring Project"
2. Try "maven package" command from Eclipse's "Run as" button > Error
3. Compile projext on command line using "mvn package"
4. Drag-drop to Tomcat webapps folder.

Now I try to figure out answers to **these questions:**

- Eclipse shows a folder with "JS" as icon, but when I open it it shows the "src" and "target" folder, also with JS icon... **What is that?**
- is there a way to "click a button" in Eclipse an compile the project AND have it **auto-deployed to my local/remote web server**?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question:

If you have configured a Server in Eclipse (for example Tomcat), and added your Project to this Server, then it auto-deployes every change in your project to the server. (Sometimes this does not work 100% correct and you have to restart the server.)

If you need more functionality you can have a look at JRebel ( http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ )

**Added**

If you Project is no Dynamic Web Project (this is if you create it as Spring Project), then you have to add the Dynamic Web Facet first.

- Project Properties/Project Facets/-> Convert to faceted from.../
- Select: Dynamic Web Project, and Java

Then you can add the project to your server.

Comment: Hm... not sure how I can do that when I already created the project as Spring Project.

Comment: The function to add the factets exists in STS Eclipse 2.3.3 which is based on Eclipse 3.6. But I don't know if the feature exist in pure Eclipse and in wich version. -- If you are missing the function to convert to faceted project, then have a look at: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/